# Javascript nullish assignment of each object member

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, destructuring

Assuming I have the following two objects

```
foo = {
  a: 10
  b: 'hello'
  c: 'world'
}

bar = {
  a:5
  b: null
  c: null
  d: "This is not in foo"
}
```

I would like to have an operation which would do the equivalent of below operation but without having to specify it for each member.

```
  bar.a ??= foo.a
  bar.b ??= foo.b
  bar.c ??= foo.c

  console.log(bar) // {a:5, b:'hello', c:'world', d:'This is not in foo'
```

Essentially: For each member of `bar`, if it is `nullish` take the value in `foo`. Leave all members which exist in `foo` but not in `bar` in peace

How would I go about this? I have tried to search a solution using destructuring in some way but with no success...

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the keys in `foo` then perform the assignment operation in the loop.

```
Object.keys(bar).forEach(k => bar[k] ??= foo[k]);
```

Comment: derpischer in their solution mentioned that if bar has some undefined properties, they would not be overwritten, is this also the case in your spread syntax solution?

Comment: No, it only replaces properties that don't exist at all. I've removed that from the answer.

Comment: Should it not be `Object.keys(bar)`...?

Comment: Yes, when I started writing the answer I had the relationship backwards, and didn't fix it properly.

Comment: I am actually using typescript and am getting some problems when trying to implement your solution. I have posted a related question about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74465046/typescript-does-not-recognize-that-iterator-can-index-class-when-using-foreach-t

Comment: I don't use TypeScript so I can't help with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a new object instead of manipulating `bar` you could do as follows

```
let newbar = Object.assign({}, foo, bar);
```

Ie, in the `Object.assign` it will first assign all properties from `foo` and then all properties from `bar`, so properties not existing in `bar` will be taken from `foo` and properties existing in `bar` will be taken from bar.

Be aware, that if `bar` has an `undefined` property, this will overwrite the value from `foo`. So

```
let bar = { a: undefined }
let foo = { a: 3 }
let combined = Object.assign({}, foo, bar);  
// will result in { a: undefined }
```

Also be aware, that this will add any property, that exists in `foo` to the result. So

```
 let bar = { a: 3 }
 let foo = { b: 4 }
 let combined = Object.assign({}, foo, bar);  
 // will result in { a: 3, b: 4 }
```

Not sure if this fits your requirement. If not, go with Barmar's solution.

Comment: How could I avoid the `undefined` problem?

Comment: -1, this does not solve the problem: “For each member of `bar`, if it is nullish take the value in `foo`”. Your proposal keep nullish values from `bar` into the resulting object.